# Let $f_1, f_2 \in E^*$ such that $\{f_1, f_2\}$ is linearly independent. Is the map $x \mapsto (f_1(x), f_2(x))$ injective or surjective?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a topological vector space and $E^*$ its topological dual. Let $f_1, f_2 \in E^*$ such that $\{f_1, f_2\}$ is linearly independent. Clearly, $f_1 \neq 0 \neq f_2$. We define
$$
F:E \to \mathbb R^2, x \mapsto (f_1(x), f_2(x)).
$$

Clearly, $E$ is infinite-dimensional and $F$ linear continuous. Are there some other special properties of $F$? Is it injective or surjective?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: It is not injective as the intersection of the kernels of $f_1$ and $f_2$ is nontrivial if $\dim E\ge 3.$ It is surjective as $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I gave a  clear answer. I have no idea why it was downvoted.

Comment: @geetha290krm I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: I will undelete it now. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of any linear map  is a linear subspace. In this case,  if the range is  one-dimensional then the range is a straight line which makes $f_1$ and $f_2$ multiples of each other. Of course the range cannot be $\{0\}$ either. So the map is onto.

It need not  be injective. For example, consider the first  two projections on $\ell^{2}$.  [ A linear map is injective if and only if its kernel is $\{0\}$. In this case $(0,0,1,0,...)$ is in the kernel so the map is not injective]. Also, the dimension of the co-domain of an injective linear map is atleast as much as the dimension of the domain. Hence, $F$ can never be injective.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured a proof and posted it as below answer.

---

> Let $E$ be a topological vector space and $E^*$ its topological dual. Let $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in E^*$ such that $\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ is linearly independent. We define
> $$
> F:E \to \mathbb R^n, x \mapsto (f_1(x), \ldots, f_n(x)).
> $$
> Then $F$ is surjective.

[Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386842/intersection-of-kernels-and-linear-dependence-of-linear-maps) Let $f, f_1, \ldots, f_n$ be linear functionals on a vector space $E$. If $\bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker f_i \subset \ker f$ then $f$ is linear dependent of $\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$.

By **Lemma**, there is $x_i \in (\bigcap_{j \neq i} \ker f_j) \setminus \ker f_i$. Then $F(x_i)$ is zero everywhere except at the $i$-th coordinate. Clearly, $\{F(x_1), \ldots, F(x_n)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$, This completes the proof.